# Error in changing vids in powerpoint using vba

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to change wmv videos to mp4 in this macro:

```
Sub mp4_to_wmv()
    Dim src, ptrn, re, Match, Matches
    ptr1 = "(\w+)"

    Create the regular expression.
    Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    re.Pattern = ptr1
    re.IgnoreCase = False
    re.Global = True

    For Each pptSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each pptShape In pptSlide.Shapes
            'If it's a video
            If pptShape.Type = msoMedia Then
                Set Matches = re.Execute(pptShape.Name)
                ' If the video is mp4 then we create the wmv video
                If Matches(1).Value = "mp4" Then
                    ' We delete the mp4 video
                    pptShape.Delete
                    ' We create the video
                    MyDocument = ActivePresentation.Path & "\" & Matches(0).Value & ".wmv"
                    ' The insertion part is the part giving me trouble,
                    Set Test = pptShape(FileName:=myDocument, Left:=156, Top:=0, Width:=2048, Height:=922)
                    ' Once we have the new video, we have to configure it to start automatically
                    Set oEffect = myDocument.TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect(myDocument.Shapes(3), msoAnimEffectMediaPlay, , msoAnimTriggerWithPrevious)
                    ' I'm not sure this part works...
                    With Test.AnimationSettings.PlaySettings
                         .PlayOnEntry = True
                         .LoopUntilStopped = msoCTrue
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

What I'm trying to do is insert this working example into the loop, but I am not being able to do it properly

```
Set myDocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

myDocument.Shapes.AddMediaObject FileName:="C:\Windows\clock.avi",Left:=5, Top:=5, Width:=100, Height:=100
```

I assume I have both videos wmv and mp4 in the current folder.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what kind of error you get (number and in which line). Did you declare `myDocument` variable (in which way)?

Comment: Finally figure it out it, I was having problems with the AddMediaObject into the loop

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub mp4_to_wmv_or_wmv_to_mp4()
Dim src, ptrn, re, Match, Matches
ptr1 = "(\w+)"

' Create the regular expression.
Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
re.Pattern = ptr1
re.IgnoreCase = False
re.Global = True

For Each pptSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each pptShape In pptSlide.Shapes
        'If it's a video
        If pptShape.Type = msoMedia Then
            Set Matches = re.Execute(pptShape.Name)
            ' If the video is mp4 then we create the wmv video
            If Matches(1).Value = "mp4" Then
                ' We load the video
                MyDocument = ActivePresentation.Path & "\" & Matches(0).Value & ".wmv"
            ElseIf Matches(1).Value = "wmv" Then
                MyDocument = ActivePresentation.Path & "\" & Matches(0).Value & ".mp4"
            ' The insertion part is the one giving me trouble, I know this works, but I am not able to integrate it within the loop
                'Set myDocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
                'myDocument.Shapes.AddMediaObject FileName:="C:\Windows\clock.avi",Left:=5, Top:=5, Width:=100, Height:=100
            Set test = pptSlide.Shapes.AddMediaObject(FileName:=MyDocument, Left:=156, Top:=0, Width:=2048, Height:=922)
            ' Once we have the new video, we have to configure it to start automatically
            'Set oEffect = myDocument.TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect(myDocument.Shapes(3), msoAnimEffectMediaPlay, , msoAnimTriggerWithPrevious)
            ' I'm not sure this part works...
            With test.AnimationSettings.PlaySettings
                 .PlayOnEntry = msoTrue
                 .LoopUntilStopped = msoCTrue
                 '.fullScreen = True
            End With
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be something along these lines:

```
    'Add the shape on the correct slide
    Set newVideoShape = pptSlide.Shapes.AddMediaObject(FileName:=MyDocument, Left:=156, Top:=0, Width:=2048, Height:=922)
    'Add the effect
    Set oEffect = pptSlide.TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect(newVideoShape, msoAnimEffectMediaPlay, , msoAnimTriggerWithPrevious)
    'Make it the first animation
    oEffect.MoveTo 1
```

I would avoid using the AnimationSettings object for anything. It is a legacy animation object (PPT 2000 and earlier) when a shape could have only one entrance animation. Using it is known to cause some unexpected results; sometimes even deleting all the animations assigned on a slide.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, three questions:
1) I've just realized my code links the video and I need them embedded, do you know what changes do I have to make?
2) Do you know how to add the fullscreen effect?

Thanks!
3) Do you know how to add the LoopUntilStopped effect?

Comment: Answer to 1 is using AddMediaObject2 I think...I'll keep on digging for fullscreen and loop effect.